# Нужна помощь с регулярным выражением | JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно во всех абзацах заменить `[ любой текст` на `...`

Например с `текст1 [ текст2` должно получиться `текст1 ...`

```js
$('body').find(".cbp").text( $(this).text().replace(/\[/g, "...") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="cbp">текст1 [ текст2</p>

<p class="cbp">текст1 [ текст2</p>

<p class="cbp">текст1 [ текст2</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Как Думаете, чему равно this?
$('body').find(".cbpthis").text(`${this===window}, ${$(this)[0] === $(window)[0]}`);

for(const p of document.getElementsByClassName('cbp')) 
    p.innerText = p.innerText.replace(/\[.+$/g, "...");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="cbpthis"></p>
<p class="cbp">текст1 [ текст2</p>

<p class="cbp">текст1 [ текст2</p>

<p class="cbp">текст1 [ текст2</p>
```

Comment: спасибо) думал раз jquery нашел элемент, то он и будет this